# How can I solve binomial congruent equations?

Tags: number-theory

[Determine whether or not the quadratic congruence $2x^2+5x-9=0\pmod {101}$ is solvable.]

I make it to perfect square form and use Legandre symbol.

$2(x+77)^2 = 60 \pmod{101}$

Is there any effective way to solve this?

Comment: Why binomial ??

Comment: Depends what you mean by "effective". You can certainly check $x=0,1,2,\dots,100$ in turn and you're guaranteed to find all the solutions (if there are any), and that's "effective" in the technical sense of the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modular inverse of $2 \pmod {101}$ is $51$ (use extended gcd algorithm to find the inverse). So we have :

$$2(x+77)^2 = 60 \pmod{101} \\\iff (x+77)^2 =3060=30 \pmod{101}$$

So you need to check if $30$ is a square, here you can use Legendre symbol.

$$\left( \frac{30}{101} \right)=\left( \frac{2}{101} \right)\left( \frac{3}{101} \right)\left( \frac{5}{101} \right)$$

$$\left( \frac{2}{101} \right)=(-1)^{\frac{101^2-1}{8}}=-1$$
$$\left( \frac{3}{101} \right)=\left( \frac{101}{3} \right)(-1)^{50}=\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)=(-1)^{\frac{3^2-1}{8}}=-1$$
$$\left( \frac{5}{101} \right)=\left( \frac{101}{5} \right)(-1)^{2\times50}=\left( \frac{1}{5} \right)=1$$

Finally $30$ is a square, so the congruence is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, if $\gcd(n,2a)=1$, we have $$ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{n}$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 4a}\iff (2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{n}$$

In this case, $$2x^2+5x-9\equiv 0\pmod{101}$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 8}\iff (4x+5)^2\equiv 97\pmod{101}$$

Using [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), we get $$\left(\frac{97}{101}\right)=\left(\frac{101}{97}\right)=\left(\frac{2^2}{97}\right)=1$$

Or notice that the congruence is equivalent to $$(4x+5)^2\equiv -4\pmod{101}$$

$$\iff \left((4x+5)2^{-1}\right)^2\equiv -1\pmod{101}$$

and $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $101=4\cdot 25+1$ by a simpler well-known fact (which also follows from [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B11_and_the_first_supplement), but it's not needed).

Also notice that if $4x+5\equiv d\pmod{101}$ (where $d$ is some square root of $97$ mod $101$), then $x\equiv 4^{-1}(d-5)\pmod{101}$.

Therefore the congruence is solvable.

For a method of solving it, see [this paper](http://course1.winona.edu/eerrthum/13Spring/SquareRoots.pdf) (in this case, page $2$, since $101$ is a prime of the form $8k+5$). Though this problem is not asking for the solutions.